# convert associative array to array of objects

Tags: php

How do I convert an array of arrays into an array of objects?

```
$a = blah // an array of arrays;

$b= (object) array( $a);

print_r($b); //prints an object of an array of arrays
```

Comment: Note that "associative array" does not mean "array of arrays".

Comment: Why do you need it to declare itself an object if it is already a key-value thing? I mean, isn't that enough? You can already refer to stuff in there with $var[$n]['key'].

Comment: What you are talking about is not associative arrays but multidimensional arrays. Associative arrays is just like a map/dictionary.

Comment: Wait, what? You have an array of arrays that you want to convert to an array of objects but you want `$b` to be an object of arrays of arrays— \*head asplode\*

Comment: I am using the php file for a flex project, which expects an array of objects. Flex is somewhat retarded and specific

Comment: @BoltClock...no. I want an array of objects. The code I have is an object of arrays of arrays...which is not what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An associative array is not an array of arrays. It is an array whose keys are strings. An array of arrays is a *multidimensional array*.

To convert a multidimensional array into an array of objects, convert each item into an object:

```
foreach(array_keys($a) as $key)
{
  $a[$key] = (object)$a[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$array = associative array

$object = new StdClass();

foreach ( $array as $key => $value ){
    $object -> $key = $value;
}

print_r ($object);
```

this is for a single dimensional array. if its multi dimensional then you need to change it into a recursive function.